# Find a basis for a kernel

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, change-of-basis

> $L: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $L(x_1, x_2) = (2x_1 + x_2, -3x_1 + 2x_2)$
>
> Find a basis for Ker($L$)

I solved $$L(x_1, x_2) = 0$$ and the only solution I have is $(x_1, x_2) = (1, 1)$, which is a finite set, so there cant be a basis right?

Comment: Is the solution $(1, 1)$ correct?

Comment: I solved and got $(x_1,x_2)=(0,0)$.

Comment: The kernel of $L$ is $\{0\}$ and $(1,1)$ is not a solution; it is $L(1,1)=(3, -1)$.

Comment: An excellent example of why it is useful to *check your answers*.